# Finding the properties of a slide

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint

If I open a PowerPoint presentation by using the VBScript, can I automatically find the template name used for each slide in the opened PowerPoint? Is there any I can find the properties of the slide?

Comment: Presentations are based on templates; all slides in a presentation will be based on the same template, Ansgar's .TemplateName property (of the presentation, note, and not a particular slide) will give answer the first question.  What specific properties of a slide are you after?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to get started with something like this would be to record it as a macro in VBA and then "translate" that macro to VBScript. Things to be observed with the translation are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info).

In your case something like this might do:

```
Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
pp.Visible = True

Set presentation = pp.Presentations.Open("C:\path\to\your.ppt")
WScript.Echo presentation.TemplateName
slide.Close
```

The layouts of each slide can be retrieved like this:

```
For Each slide In presentation.Slides
  WScript.Echo slide.Layout
Next
```

Note that this will return the number of the layout. If you want a name, you'll have to create a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4) mapping the numbers to [layout names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.ppslidelayout).

Comment: what i mean by here is if i have a presentation with slide 1 contains the "Title and content theme", slide 2 contains the "content with caption theme" my presentation is like this with different themes for each slide. i want find the theme of each slide programatically by using VBScript

Comment: Thanks ansgar, one more question can't we work with out having visible as True? i don't want the ppt to open on screeen. i tried by commenting and giving the option as false but i got error "Invalid request.  Hiding the application window is not allowed."

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this works in VBS but in VBA you can:

```
Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
'pp.Visible = True

Set presentation = pp.Presentations.Open("C:\path\to\your.ppt", False, False, False)
```

Presentations.Open normally opens a presentation in a new visible window; in order to do this, the application must be visible (else you get an error).  That's why you needed to make PPT visible.  If you open the presentation windowless (the last False parm above), you shouldn't need to make the app visible.